# Compiled C program with call to undefined/undeclared function; no error or warning reported. Why?

Tags: c, gcc

I'm copying an example from Kernighan & Ritchie's "C Programming Language (2nd Edition)". Just to make sure I had copied the code correctly (and to test its functionality), I compiled this code:

```
/*This is an example program from chapter 5, section 6 (Pointer Arrays; Pointers to Pointers)*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "/home/alecto/Compsci/Cprogramming/Utils/get_line.c"
#include "/home/alecto/Compsci/Cprogramming/Kernighan_Ritchie_5/alloc.c"

#define MAXLINES 5000 /*max number of lines to be sorted*/

char *lineptr[MAXLINES]; /*pointers to lines of text*/

int readlines(char *lineptr[], int nlines);
void writelines(char *lineptr[], int nlines);
void qsort(char *lineptr[], int left, int right);

/* sort input lines */
main()
{
  int nlines; /* number of input lines read */

  if ((nlines = readlines(lineptr, MAXLINES)) >= 0) {
    qsort(lineptr, 0, nlines-1);
    writelines(lineptr, nlines);
    return 0;
  }
  else {
    printf("error: input too big for sort\n");
    return 1;
  }
}
... //readlines() and writelines() are defined in my source file, but not
... //qsort()
```

The program compiles with no complaints from gcc or the linker, despite the lack of a definition for `qsort()` in the source file.  I tried commenting out the declaration `void qsort(char *lineptr[], int left, int right);` while leaving the call to `qsort()` active in `main()` just to see if I could induce an error, but the program still manages to compile *and run* silently, without complaint or unexpected behaviour

What's going on here?

Comment: How would we distinguish the observed behaviour from the program working?

Comment: `qsort()`is part of the standard C library.

Comment: *How* do you compile? What compiler are you using, and which version? What flags are you passing to the compiler?

Comment: When I run the program in the terminal, it takes input from the console until EOF is reached.  Each `'\n'` writes a pointer to the next available index in a buffer that is private to `alloc()`, and that pointer indicates the address of the first character in a string read from input. In the present version I have written, once EOF is read, `writelines()` prints each string in order. In the completed program, where `qsort()` is defined, the strings should come out in alphabetical order. My problem is that the current version works at all, even with an undeclared `qsort()`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg `gcc 4.8.2`, and the only option I'm using at the command line is `-o`. I don't have enough facility with `gcc` to tell you what the default warning levels are set at.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`qsort` is a standard library function, declared in `<stdlib.h>`.

The *compiler* needs a visible *declaration* of `qsort`, and you've provided such a declaration in your source file.

The *linker* needs a *definition* of `qsort`; that's provided by the standard C library. That function is incompatible with your declaration, but that's not an error that linkers typically can detect.

Because you've declared a standard library function in a manner that's incompatible with the actual function, your program has undefined behavior.

As for why your program still compiles when you remove your declaration of `qsort`, that's because it's following an old version of the C standard. As of the C90 standard, it's legal to call a function with no visible declaration; the compiler *assumes* that the function returns an `int`. C99 dropped the "implicit `int`" rule, requiring a compile-time diagnostic for such a call -- but gcc still follows the C90 standard (with gcc-specific extensions) by default. Use `-std=c99` or `-std=c11` to ask gcc to conform to a more modern edition of the C standard; add `-pedantic -Wall -Wextra` to get more warnings.

That's how to get the compiler to diagnose your error (trying to redeclare `qsort`). To *fix* that error, you need to use a name other than `qsort` *and* you need to provide a valid declaration and definition.

Also, it rarely makes sense to have a `#include` directive for a `.c` files. Normally `.c` files (which provide definitions) are compiled separately, and `.h` files (which provide declarations) are `#include`d. That's a convention, not a language rule, but following it makes organizing your code much easier. There's more to know about how to do this (header guards, how to link multiple objects into a single program, etc.), but that's beyond the scope of this question.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that you are not including header files, you are including the complete *source* files, creating a single [*translation unit*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_%28programming%29). Since the functions are both declared and defined in those included files, you get no error because the compiler *have* the declarations.

If you separated the compilation, and compiled each source file separately (and removed those include directives) then you would get if not errors at least warnings.

Answer (score 1):

`qsort()` is included in `<stdlib.h>`; so even though the arguments in my calls to this function shouldn't make any sense to the compiler, referencing `qsort()` after including it via the library seems to be perfectly legal.

@mfro if you'll post an answer saying something to this effect, I'll give you credit for the answer.